# Amazon RDS security group - how to modify by AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have already setup my RDS environment. I also have configured my Security Groups before and I can modify my RDS security group on Amazon web console as well. So everything works by hand!
The question is, how can I modify the Security Group for a RDS using AWS SDK (preferably Java). To be more clear, I like to add more security groups to my RDS instance using AWS SDK (or AWS CLI).

I have already taken a look at [Amazon VPC Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html), but didn't get anything out of it.

Comment: By AWS means I did not get you? You want to say AWS Dashboard and AWS CLI?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I meant using AWS SDK or AWS CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. I try to explain the API in Java but there is a similar way to do it with CLI command too.

***AmazonRDSClient*** has a ***modifyDBInstance*** method that takes ***ModifyDBInstanceRequest*** as the parameter.

Depending on the **RDS Security Group** type, you can set the security groups for your RDS instance.
RDS Security Groups are explained on [AWS user guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html).

```
    AmazonRDSClient client = ... //initialize Amazon RDS Client
    String dBInstanceIdentifier = ... //DB instance identifier
    List<String> vpcSecurityGroupIds = ... //List of VPC Security Group Ids

    ModifyDBInstanceRequest request = new ModifyDBInstanceRequest(dBInstanceIdentifier);
    request.setApplyImmediately(true);
    //request.setDBSecurityGroups(dbSecurityGroupIds);
    request.setVpcSecurityGroupIds(vpcSecurityGroupIds);

    DBInstance result = client.modifyDBInstance(request);
```

Use setVpcSecurityGroupIds method if you are trying to set VPC Security Groups or use setDBSecurityGroups if you like to set DB Security Groups.